# I want to learn the location of files on SFTP Server

Tags: android, sftp, jsch

I need a code for learning location of files on server.I can learn name of files but i don't learn location.For example i want to learn abc.txt like (\home\user1\desktop\abc.txt)

```
try {
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
session = jsch.getSession("***", "***.***.***.***",22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword("****");
session.connect();                  
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
sftpChannel.exit(); 
session.disconnect(); }catch(JSchException e){writeToSDFile(" "+e.toString());}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pwd()` and `lpwd()` (operations of the `ChannelSFTP` class) to retrieve the local and remote working directory. For more info hav a look at [JSch's API](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/).

To complete your code sample:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
session = jsch.getSession("***", "***.***.***.***",22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword("****");
session.connect();                  
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

System.out.println(sftpChannel.pwd());
System.out.println(sftpChannel.lpwd());

sftpChannel.exit(); 
session.disconnect(); }catch(JSchException e){writeToSDFile(" "+e.toString());}
```

Comment: thank you very very much,i have searched this 2 weeks,and you helped me,you are king.thanks thanks thanks :)